# How to clear TextBlock

Tags: wpf, textblock

I'm adding text TextBlock Text1,Text2,Text3 in Adddata() function as follow.

```
if (i == 0)
{
    Text1.Text = tagname.AlarmTag;
}
if (i == 1)
{
    Text2.Text = tagname.AlarmTag;
}
if (i == 2)
{
    Text3.Text = tagname.AlarmTag;
}
```

Now in deletedata() I want to clear all contents in three textblock.
How can I do that? Because I cannot find Clear option. I want to clear text of three textblock at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "clear" the data :

```
Text1.Text = String.Empty;
Text2.Text = String.Empty;
Text3.Text = String.Empty;
```

Comment: I can't do this.because i have selectionchnaged coding for that.So if i set null to thta textblock,when i mouseclick it will return the null string.

Comment: Where does NULL come into this?  Your just setting the controls to display an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the text of the textbox to an empty string.

```
Text1.Text = "";
Text2.Text = "";
Text3.Text = "";
```

You could also define your own extension method.

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void Clear(this TextBox text)
    {
        text.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Then, just include a `using` directive for the namespace you defined your extension class in, and you can do:

```
Text1.Clear();
Text2.Clear();
Text3.Clear();
```

Comment: Can u please explain more,which directive i have to include.Because im doing all this coding in main class only.(Just im moving Vc++ to C# so i dont know much about using etc.,)

namespace WpfApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
}

My all funcitons...
}

Comment: I would create a new file (ControlExtensions.cs) with that class inside of it. Make the namespace for this new file `WpfApp.Extensions`. In your original file (with your main class), add `using WpfApp.Extensions;` at the top to enable the new method.

Answer (score 0):

Set their text to an empty string?